# Mocha Chai test case for angular configuration file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, chai

I am getting a hard time to resolve mocha chai test case for angular js configuration file .

```
angular.module('myApp.myModule', []).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('myModule', {
  url: '/myModule',
  templateUrl: function(){
    return 'scripts/my-module/views/my-module.html';
  },
  controller: 'myModuleCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
  css: 'styles/lazy-load/my-module.css'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

})

I need to cover mocha chai test case for return function of "templateUrl" which is returning a url ('scripts/my-module/views/my-module.html').

[image]

Comment: Are you getting some error. I am not sure what you are trying to test.

Comment: I have changed templateUrl : "scripts/my-module/views/my-module.html" to templateUrl: function(){ return 'scripts/my-module/views/my-module.html';} which reduces Karma test code coverage. so i am trying to cover this function through my controller. without return type function to templateUrl code coverage was full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like

```
it('should load the page.', inject(function ($state) {
    var state = $state.get('selectLine');
    assert.isDefined(state.templateUrl()); 
    expect(state.templateUrl()).to.equal('scripts/select-line-module/views/select-line.html');
}));
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to inject `$location` and `$route` service into your test. Setup a whenGET to intercept the actual request and then check the `$location` and `$route` configuration after the transition is complete. I did something similar earlier

```
it("should load the page.", inject(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, $httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET("scripts/my-module/views/my-module.html").respond("<div/>");
        $location.path("/myModule");
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($location.path()).toBe("/myModule");
    }));
```

I was using `$route` service you would require `$state` service.

Comment: Getting an Error : [$injector:unpr]Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

Comment: As i said inject the $state service not $route.

Comment: it("should load the page.", inject(function ($location, $rootScope, $state, $httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET("scripts/my-module/views/my-module.html").respond("<div/>");
        $location.path("/my-module");
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($location.path()).toBe("/my-module");
    }));   This gives undefined is not a function at expect

Comment: This test was against jasmine, may the assertion statements in mocha are different.

Comment: i am using mocha-chai

Comment: i created different thread ,that may explain better ....    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719108/mocha-chai-test-case-for-angularjs-ui-route