# mocha chai test case for angularjs ui-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, chai

I need to cover angularJs config file through mocha chai

[image]

i tried

```
it('should load the page.', inject(function ($location, $rootScope, $state, $httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('scripts/select-line-module/views/select-line.html').respond('<div/>');
    var state = $state.get('selectLine');
    $rootScope.$digest();
    assert.isDefined(state.templateUrl()); 
    expect(state.templateUrl).toBe('scripts/select-line-module/views/select-line.html');
}));
```

I am able to cover templateUrl function but test case is failing 
 error : undefined is not a function

[image]

I feel i am close , but what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You assertation and expectation are changed. You must assert the function templateUrl is defined and expect the function return to be a string.

assert.isDefined(state.templateUrl);
expect(state.templateUrl()).toBe('scripts/select-line-module/views/select-line.html');

However, can you check if state is defined?  I think it can be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like

```
it('should load the page.', inject(function ($state) {
    var state = $state.get('selectLine');
    assert.isDefined(state.templateUrl()); 
    expect(state.templateUrl()).to.equal('scripts/select-line-module/views/select-line.html');
}));
```

This works for me